# The optimization result change after shorten the equation

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

Assume that I have a function:

$$f_{w_1,w_2}(x)=w_2(w_1x)$$

I want to find the optimal point of function $f$, so I will follow the gradient:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_1} = w_2x, \frac{\partial f}{\partial w_2} = w_1x$$

Then I update the parameter:
$$\Rightarrow 
\begin{cases} 
w'_1 = w_1-w_2x \\ w'_2=w_2-w_1x 
\end{cases}$$
$$\Rightarrow f_{w'_1w'_2}(x)=(w_2-w_1x)(w_1-w_2x)(x)$$

Now, let assume $w=w_1w_2$ then do the similar thing

$$f_w(x)=wx$$ $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}=x$$ $$w' = w-x$$ $$f_w(x) = (w-x)x$$

It's clearly that $f_{w'_1w'_2}(x)\ne f_w(x)$ which means by shortening the equation, we can get the better or worse optimization result. It sounds unclear to me, I think I am wrong somewhere, please tell me where to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If you set $w_1=w_2$ your equation should become $f_w=w^2x$

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, if $w_1$ = $w_2$, then the equation is $f_{w_1}=w_1^2x$, since I set $w = w_1w_2$ so the equation still be $f_w =wx$, isn't it?

Comment: In your original equation $x$ is multiplied by two constants.  If you take $w_1=w_2=3=w$ you have $f_{3,3}(x)=3(3x)=9x=w^2x$

Comment: Really really sorry for the super late reply, what if $w_1$ and $w_2$ are different?

Comment: Then you have the definition in the first line and can take partial derivatives of that.  Your whole question was what happens when they are equal.

Comment: So the second derivative option only happen in the scenario where $w_1=w_2$, if not, I can't assume that $w=w_1 \times w_2 \Rightarrow f_w(x) = f_{w_1,w_2}$ and update $f_w(x)$ with parameter $w$. Is that your point?

Comment: As the function is linear in $w_1, w_2$ the second derivative with respect to either will be $0$.  There will be a nonzero mixed second derivative, where you take one derivative with respect to each variable.  I am not sure I am answering what you are asking.

Comment: I think my question has some unclear points, I will have to learn more about linear algebra and clarify it later. Thank you for your patient, I already upvote but did not check as an answer since I'm not sure it's correct or not.